# SMTP connect() failed

Tags: php, email, web, phpmailer

Reciently, in one webpage installed in localhost, I configurated the PHPMAILER, and works perfectly. It sents the emails to my gmail account.
But, with the same configuration, uploaded the webpage to internet, and gives "Error: SMTP connect() failed."

I tryed alot of examples and tons of "solution answers" and it continues giving the error.

Here is my actual configuration file:

```
include("mailer/class.phpmailer.php");
include("mailer/class.smtp.php") ;
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->IsSMTP(); 


$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      
$mail->Port       = 465;                   
$mail->Username   = "myemail@gmail.com";  
$mail->Password   = "supersecurepassword";            
$mail->SetFrom($email, $name);

$mail->AddReplyTo("myemails@gmail.com","Test");

$mail->Subject    = $subject;



$mail->MsgHTML("Email enviado por: ".$email."<br/>".$contact_message);

$address = "email@gmail.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "pedo");
if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your host is blocking the SMTP port.

Comment: try telnetting to smtp.gmail.com at port 465 on the box just to check your connectivity.

Comment: The webpage its hosted in my dedicated server. Have all the ports open.

Comment: @PabloFornes Your dedicated server is connected to your dedicated router and has a dedicated firewall that is wide open for routing outbound traffic?

Comment: The dedicated server dont have a firewall. Its a OVH server with Ubuntu Server 12.04

Comment: I made a telnet smtp.gmail.com 465
And connects to the smtp server

Comment: You could try [reading the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting), and upgrading to a recent version while you're there. Don't use `ssl` on 465; use `tls` on 587.

Comment: Tested with the tls configuration and dont works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google was blocking my loggin attemtps all the time.
Here: [click here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754) google said me that he dont was accepting my user and my pass.
Clicked [here](http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha) he unlocked my account to use it on my web. 
Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the port 587 as usually the port 25 is closed by the ISP.